# How to update multiple documents?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I want to update multiple documents.
My current Document,
Document **Account**

```
{
    "_id" : "5cbd96aca1a6363473d4g8745",
    "contact" : [
         "5cbd96aca1a6363473d4a968",
    ]
},
{
    "_id" : "5cbd96aca1a6363473d4g8746",
    "contact" : [             
         "5cbd96aca1a6363473d4z7632",
    ]
}
```

I need below output,
update contact array with different **_id**.
Document **Account**

```
{
    "_id" : "5cbd96aca1a6363473d4g8745",
    "contact" : [
         "5c98833f98770728a7047f1a",
         "5cbd96aca1a6363473d4a968",
    ]
},
{
    "_id" : "5cbd96aca1a6363473d4g8746",
    "contact" : [     
         "5caddf78b8c0645402090536",        
         "5cbd96aca1a6363473d4z763",
    ]
}
```

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/Bulk.find.update/
please check this.

Comment: You want to push ID in array while updating values ?

Comment: Yes i want to push _ids in array

Comment: @ManojGhediya use `$addToSet` or `$push` to push id with bulk update.

Comment: Yes its work, Thanks..!!

Comment: @ManojGhediya cool! mark it as answer. :)

Comment: Also if you might want to remove _id from array use `$pull`

Comment: @AbhishekMani Why we use bulk update?

Comment: @ManojGhediya If you want to update multiple documents at a time. Since you need to search multiple doc and update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `$addToSet` or `$push` to push id with `bulk update`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use update with upsert. It will update the doc if exist and if not then it will create new one.
for example:

```
//Make a obj to set
var contacts = {
  id: req.body.id,
  contactIds: req.body.contactIds,
};

req.app.db.models.ModelsName.update(
{
//if you want multiple fields to be update
  $and: [{ id: contacts.id }, { contactIds: { $in: contacts.contactIds } }]
},

//Set the above obj 
{ $set: contacts },
{ upsert: true },
(err, result) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err.message)
  }
  console.log("Updated successfully")
})
```

This is just a reference. Modify accordingly your use.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Bulk.find.update() method to update all matching documents. 
example:
`var bulk = db.items.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();
bulk.find( { status: "D" } ).update( { $set: { status: "I", points: "0" } } );
bulk.find( { item: null } ).update( { $set: { item: "TBD" } } );
bulk.execute();`